# Flink: merging results over all keys in time windows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream of data from Kafka:

```
stream
    .keyBy("key")
    .window(<tumbling window of 5 mins>)
    .aggregate(<aggFunc>, <function adding window key and start wd time>)
    ...
    .addSink(sink)
```

The number of keys in 1 window is dynamic (window 1 has 3 keys, window 2 can have 4 keys).

Window 1 output: 5 mins - 00:00 to 00:05 for example. Numbering only for reference later, each record is a POJO, here I kept only to the important fields.

```
1. (<aggregated val>, key1, <window1-start-time)
2. (<aggregated val>, key2, <window1-start-time)
3. (<aggregated val>, key3, <window1-start-time)
```

Window 2 output: 00:05 to 00:05-00:10

```
4. (<aggregated val>, key1, <window1-start-time)
5. (<aggregated val>, key3, <window2-start-time)
6. (<aggregated val>, key4, <window2-start-time)
7. (<aggregated val>, key5, <window2-start-time)
```

**What I want:** string(list of json object)

```
[json-string(1), json-string(2), json-string(3)] 
-> send to sink after window 1 fires
[json-string(4), json-string(5), json-string(6), json-string(7)] 
-> send to sink after window 2 fires
```

My sink is an endpoint for HTTP request accepting json payload. And I want to batch all my keys in a window and send to the sink once for each window. **How to do that?**

I currently use CountWindowAll but that is not optimal because the countWindow may include data from 2 windows. I'm thinking about another TublingWindow after apply but don't know **how Flink derives timestamp after apply**.

I'm using EventTime that derived timestamp from a field in Kafka record. After apply operator, the event does not have that timestamp record anymore but a Long windowStartTime.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? As for dynamic keys, it is normal that any given window will only include a subset of the keys -- you don't have to do anything special. As for timestamps, Flink isn't aware of the timestamps in your events -- when working in event time, your events are wrapped in StreamRecords that contain timestamps derived from your timestamp extractor. TimeWindows emit StreamRecords with timestamps set to the window's end time. You can follow one TimeWindow with another so long as the timeframe of the 2nd window is the same or a multiple of the 1st.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I just edited the question, hope it shows my intention clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow your keyed TimeWindow with a non-keyed TimeWindowAll that pulls together all of the results of the first window:

```
stream
    .keyBy("key")
    .window(<tumbling window of 5 mins>)
    .aggregate(<aggFunc>, <function adding window key and start wd time>)
    .windowAll(<tumbling window of 5 mins>)
    .process(<function iterating over batch of keys for each window>)
    .addSink(sink)
```

The records emitted by a timewindow are automatically timestamped in a way that permits another layer of windowing to be applied. This can be used to aggregate results across all the keys (as shown here), or to produce keyed results on different time scales (e.g., merging 5-minute windows into 60-minute windows).

The Flink training includes an [exercise](https://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/hourlyTips.html) that illustrates this pattern.